# Programmatically stream audio in Cocoa on the Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, audio, stream

How do I go about programmatically creating audio streams using Cocoa on the Mac. To make, say a white-noise generator using core frameworks on Mac OSX in Cocoa apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using the [CoreAudio](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudio/book_intro/chapter_1_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001108-CH201-DontLinkElementID_85) DefaultOutputUnit.

You can configure it with parameters such as output sampling rate, resolution, and output sample format.  Then you can programmatically create a raw sound wave and provide this to the output unit.

Take a look at this example on your machine at /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/SimpleSDK/DefaultOutputUnit/

Which uses the default output unit to play a programmatically rendered sine wave.  Using that as a starting point and you can write a routine to render any thing else to output.

This location at /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/ also contains tons of other core audio examples.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html).